# Videos that don't have thumbnails stutter while I play/move forward/move backward in VLC

Tags: video, graphics-card, vlc-media-player

I download tutorial videos and study them at my convenience.

I noticed there are two types of videos in my case:

1. Those that have a thumbnail preview after I have downloaded them.
2. Those that just show a VLC icon.

In the second case, when I press the right/left arrow key to move 10 seconds ahead or behind, the video takes a second or two to load, which was not the case with Type 1 videos. **Both videos are MP4.**

**This video below stutters**

[image: The video that stutters]

**This video below is the smooth video**

[image: The video that is smooth]

**Can somebody tell me how do it fix it ?**

System Information:

Windows 10 home, Intel core i5 7200U @2.5 GHz, 16 GB ram, Intel HD graphics 620

VLC version: 3.0.11 Vetinari

Comment: are they some type and codecs? when you open the file in vlc select "window", "media information" (this on macOS).

Comment: @Zina Hi. Thanks for helping. I have made an edit and uploaded screenshot of the same.

Comment: "Both videos are MP4" -> MP4 is a container format that can contain a large variety for videos. There are dozen of encoders with thousand of options that end up in different videos regarding e.g. key- and intermediate frames. If you want to skip 10 seconds and no key frame is right before the skip position then VLC has to computer all intermediate frames up to the skip point.

Comment: the screenshot you added is from one video, would you add the same for the other?

Comment: @Robert I will look into what you said about intermediate frames. maybe that will help.

Comment: @Zina Hey. I have uploaded the information from a similar video.